# node.js express and edit-google-spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, forms, express, google-forms

I can POST to a google form from HTML if I setup like this:

```
  <form form action="GOOGLE_FORM_RESPONSE_URL" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="entry.191678976" placeholder="Name" ></input><br>
  <input type="text" name="entry.1387050595" placeholder="Age"></input><br>   
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!"></input>
  </form>
```

I have set up a node.js server using express, and would like for the HTML to submit to the node server, at which point the node server parses the form data and submits to google. It is all working, except for the submit to google part, and I'll explain more below:

```
HTML:
  <form form action="/add" method="POST" name="top"> 
  <input type="text" name="namefield" placeholder="Name" ></input><br>
  <input type="text" name="agefield" placeholder="Age"></input><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!"></input>
  </form>
```

Using body-parser, express, and requestify to do the following:

```
app.js:
app.post('/add', function (req, res) {
var Name = req.body.namefield;
var Age = req.body.agefield;
requestify.post('GOOGLE_FORM_RESPONSE_URL', {
    "entry.191678976": Name,
    "entry.1387050595": Age 
})
.then(function(response){
    response.getBody();
    res.send(response.body);
});

    console.log(Name);
    console.log(Age);

});
```

It successfully grabs the form values (they print to console) but it doesn't pass them to google correctly (google shows form with empty fields).

**EDIT:** I ended up just using this guide, much easier than the form method https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2014/03/04/accessing-google-spreadsheets-from-node-js/

The only thing: Do I have to call Spreadsheet.load and everything inside it every time I want to do something like spreadsheet.add? If not, any literature that will explain why/how?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please include the most relevant parts of the linked sources. By the other hand looks that the question evolved too much that makes the that the title doesn't match the current question.